# Как сделать чат с админом?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте... извините, я не русский, могу допускать грамматические ошибки.

Вот вопрос такой: я создал сайт на локалхосте, е-магазин. Хочу, чтобы там был онлайн-чат с админом. Если админ будет онлайн, то откроется окно (ну, это не очень важно). Просто мне нужен принцип, алгоритм и где найти? Вообще, на локалхосте можно это реализовать? Или лучше на хостинге делать всё это?

Заранее спасибо, буду ждать помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас таблица онлайн есть? Или где-то, где отслеживается последнее подключение администратора? Если да, то можно сделать так

```
<?
$time = time()
$sql= mysql_query("select id,last from users where id=[id admina]") 
// или сразу в запросе, где where можно поставить условие 
if(($time-$sql['last']) < 900){
// тут скрипт чата
}
?>
```

Насчет запроса: где last - это колонка в таблице юзер. Может, у вас она называется по-другому или вообще нет. Это я так, пример.